# trying to simulate a card flip by using transform to flip a div and show another div

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make a set of divs which flip.... sort of like flipping over a notecard.

It seems that when i hover though, it flips and becomes white because i have show none on.  I dont know how to get the other (.back) to show.

Here is a fiddle i created
https://jsfiddle.net/q2ukg0cz/

Its a simple:

```
 <div class="flip-card">
   <div class=front">Hello</div>
   <div class="back">World</div>
 </div>
```

Im not sure what i am doing wrong in this case.

```css
div.flip-card {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-perspective: 600px;
  perspective: 600px;
}
div.flip-card > div.front,
div.flip-card > div.back {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
div.flip-card > div.front {
  background: #888;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg);
  transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg);
}
div.flip-card > div.back {
  background: #444;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
div.flip-card > div.front:hover {
  background: #444;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
div.flip-card > div.back:hover {
  background: #888;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
  transform: rotateY(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is with your selector to fire flip flop

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q2ukg0cz/1/)

try this one

```
div.flip-card {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-perspective: 600px;
  perspective: 600px;
}

div.flip-card > div.front,
div.flip-card > div.back {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

div.flip-card > div.front {
  background: #888;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg);
  transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg);
}

div.flip-card > div.back {
  background: #444;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

div.flip-card:hover > div.front {
  background: #444;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

div.flip-card:hover > div.back {
  background: #888;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
  transform: rotateY(0);
}
```

Comment: got ya!   I have to apply it to the parent!  Thanks a lot